# Slight customization to bibtex cites in LyX

Tags: bibliographies, lyx

I am using `LyX` and `BibTeX` for my bibliography. I would like the following setup for my citations:

1. In the text a cite should have a comma between the last author name and year `(LAST_NAME, YEAR)`.
2. Every time four or more authors are on a paper I want the first use to spell out each author and then use et al. All authors should be listed if the total number of authors is less than or equal to 3
3. In the bibliography it should follow the format `LAST_NAME, FIRST_INITIAL.` for the first author and `FIRST_INITIAL. LAST_NAME` for subsequent authors.

I am using `natbib` with the style `author-year` and have tried using a lot of different threads to fix this issue. A few hours later, I thought it would be easier to ask.

Comment: Which bibliography style do you use at the moment? Have you considered using the `abbrvnat` style?

Comment: @Mico I am using natbib, but am open to suggestions to get me to my desired output

Comment: It should be relatively easy to do with `biblatex` (which has a `natbib` emulation mode).

Comment: @Bernard How so in LyX?

Comment: I don't know LyX, but I suppose some code must be written. Do you know a way to incorporate code in LyX (it would be a sort of template that LyX would use for bibliographies)?

Comment: There is a little bit of work required for `biblatex` in LyX, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146159/how-do-i-make-my-bibliography-according-to-harvard-style-author-year-alphabeti/148410#148410 When Mico asks for bibliographystyle, i meant the style you can choose in the dialog that pops up when you do Insert --> ToC/List --> BibTeX bibliography.

Answer (score 1):

I'll address your objectives sequentially:

- To get the desired citation style -- author(s) and year separated by comma, parentheses placed around the entire citation block -- you should

  - use the citation command `\citep` to generate the citation callouts, and
  - load the `natbib` package with the options `comma` and `authoryear`.
- To list all authors the *first time* a piece is cited, regardless of the number of authors, load the `natbib` package with the option `longnamesfirst`.

  The two preceding suggestions can be combined, i.e., you could load the `natbib` package as follows:

  ```
  \usepackage[comma,authoryear,longnamesfirst]{natbib}
  ```
- In order never to truncate the list authors to "FirstAuth et al" in the citation callout if the piece has *three or fewer authors*, you will need to edit the bibliography style file a bit. For step by step instructions on how to modify the style file, have a look at my answer to the posting [Citation "et al." only for four and more authors with natbib and jf.bst](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196750/5001). That posting applies not only to the `jf` style, but to many others as well. (Unfortunately you haven't indicated which style you would like to use, so I can't be more specific.)
- To abbreviate authors' first and middle names, you will need to select an appropriate style file. I suggest you take a look at the style `abbrvnat.bst` and decide if its overall style works for you. If it does, you should find it straightforward to modify that file along the lines suggested in the previous bullet point to change the citation truncation scheme.