# Citation “et al.” only for four and more authors with natbib and apalike2.bst

Tags: natbib, author-number

I kinda have the exactly the same problem as the

[Citation "et al." only for four and more authors with natbib and jf.bst](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196750/citation-et-al-only-for-four-and-more-authors-with-natbib-and-jf-bst/196751#196751?newreg=e01345f67f1140b89c4d4064f8455d80)

except that I'm using `apalike2.bst`

What I did was the following: I copied the file `apalike2.bst` to my folder and renamed it to `jf3.bst` (no creativity for the name)
Then, I copied the functions

```
FUNCTION {bbl.and}
{ "and"}

FUNCTION {space.word}
{ " " swap$ * " " * }
```

to the file. Last, I replaced the `FUNCTION{format.lab.names}` by the one in the referred link above. For one, two, four or more authors everything is working well  but when i have three authors the last name of the last author and the year of the work is no appearing. For example, in the reference

```
@article{KrohlingMauro2011,
title = "Swarm algorithms with chaotic jumps applied to noisy optimization problems ",
journal = "Information Sciences ",
volume = "181",
number = "20",
pages = "4494 - 4514",
year = "2011",
issn = "0020-0255",
author = "Eduardo Mendel and Renato A. Krohling and Mauro Campos"
}
```

what I am getting is `(Mendel, Krohling)` using `\citep` and `Mendel (Krohling)` using `\citet` and what I'd like would be `(Mendel, Krohling & Campos, 2008)` or `Mendel, Krohling & Campos (2008)`depending if it is citet or citep. Oh, and I also change `bbl.and` to

```
FUNCTION {bbl.and}
{ " \& "}
```

Comment: Please tell us more about what exactly you have done. And, do tell us whether you re-ran LaTeX, then BibTeX, and then LaTeX twice more after creating the modified version of the `apalike2` style.

Comment: Thank you @Mico. I edited the question to explain in a more detailed manner. About the compiling, procedure, yes, i re-ran Latex, Bibtex and Latex.

Comment: I've looked into the code in `apalike2.bst`, and I am able to replicate the problem you've encountered. Unfortunately, I seem to be unable to diagnose the cause of the problem, let alone provide a fix. I would therefore like to suggest that you acquaint yourself with the `makebst` utility, which is part of the [custom-bib](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib) package. It provides a question-and-multiple-choice format, and at the end you will have a custom-built bibliography style file.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you very very much for trying though. I'll follow your suggestion then. Thanks again @Mico.

Comment: Yes, makebst solved my problem. If I remember correctly, the problem was something with the language....I don't remember exactly, but I was able to fix it using makebst.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved by comments.