# latex citations "et al." with "JF.BST" file

Tags: bibtex

I am trying to produce a bibliography style in the file "jf.bst" that uses "et al." whenever there are more than three authors. E.g.: "Myers et al. (2020) provide evidence that potatoes are delicious." as opposed to " Myers, Pedersen, Stuart and Jameson (2020) provide evidence that potatoes are delicious."

The file jf.bst is available here: http://faculty.haas.berkeley.edu/stanton/texintro/

This question was asked a while ago by someone else here: [Fix a .bst file to display "Author et al. (year)" if a .bib entry contains more than 2 authors?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/349475/fix-a-bst-file-to-display-author-et-al-year-if-a-bib-entry-contains-more)

I've tried to use the solution proposed there but now I get "et al." for more than 2 authors instead of 3 (see code below) which is not the goal either...

Thanks

```
   %%%KCB:  Change format of labels:
    FUNCTION {format.lab.names}
    { 's :=
      s num.names$ 'numnames :=
      s #1 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
      numnames #1 >
        { s #2 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ 't :=
          numnames #2 >
          t "others" =
          or
            { " et~al." * }
            { " and " * t * }
          if$
        }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
```

Comment: Clicking on the `jf.bst` link in the depository you mention generates a dreaded "404 - File or directory not found" error.

Comment: @Mico thanks. try this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/knpidhtozd49sjt/JF.BST?dl=0.