# ecology.bst and using bibtex

Tags: bibtex

My tags are follows:

I used the `ecology.bst` file, which is available on [https://www.cas.miamioh.edu/~stevenmh/ecology.bst](https://www.cas.miamioh.edu/%7Estevenmh/ecology.bst)

**Content of my TeX File**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@article{Ahrestani:2013hc,
    Author = {Ahrestani, Farshid S. and Hebblewhite, Mark and Post, Eric},
    Date-Added = {2014-02-26 14:22:46 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-02-26 14:22:47 +0000},
    Journal = {Scientific Reports},
    Pages = {31250},
    Title = {The importance of observation versus process error in analyses of global ungulate populations},
    Volume = {3},
    Year = {2013}}

@article{Anderson:1979dq,
    Author = {Anderson, R. M. and May, R. M.},
    Date-Added = {2013-02-20 21:55:12 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2013-02-20 21:55:13 +0000},
    Journal = {Nature},
    Number = {5721},
    Pages = {361-367},
    Title = {Population biology of infectious diseases: Part 1},
    Volume = {280},
    Year = {1979}}

@book{Bolker:2008uq,
    Author = {Bolker, B.},
    Date-Added = {2013-04-06 16:40:18 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2013-04-06 16:40:18 +0000},
    Pages = {408},
    Publisher = {Princeton, NJ: Princeton University Press},
    Title = {Ecological models and data in {R}},
    Year = {2008}}

@article{Bolker:emb,
    Author = {Bolker, B.},
    Date-Added = {2014-06-22 19:04:40 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-06-22 19:04:40 +0000},
    Journal = {url: http://ms.mcmaster.ca/~bolker/emdbook/},
    Title = {emdbook: Ecological models and data (book support). {R} package vernon 1.3.4},
    Year = {2013}}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\cite{Ahrestani:2013hc,Anderson:1979dq,Bolker:2008uq,Bolker:emb,}

\bibliographystyle{ecology}
\bibliography{\jobname.bib}



\end{document}
```

My requirement is, to add `three emdash rule` if the same author name repeats, also if an entry having two author names only, then should print comma before the second author name (refer the screenshot image) , note that if an entry having three author names then it works perfectly (so should keep the current output as is). Kindly advise.

[image]

Note that, please excuse me if my English is poor

Comment: I believe you have to modify the `linenumbers 354` and `355` (        { s nameptr "{f.~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$  }
        { s nameptr "{vv~}{ll}{, f.}{, jj}" format.name$  }
) for the requirement, but don't know how to modify, hence don't have much knowledge in .bst format file, sorry.