# LaTeX/BibTex: Truncating 4-or-more authors in bibliography

Tags: bibtex, bibliographystyle, bst

This is a follow-up question to [Citation "et al." only for four and more authors with natbib and jf.bst](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196750/citation-et-al-only-for-four-and-more-authors-with-natbib-and-jf-bst)

I just tried the answer given there, hoping it would solve our BibTex problem: Our journal requires, for references with 3 authors, to name all authors in both citation and bibliography; 4 or more authors should be truncated to 1st-author-plus-et-al in both citation and bibliography.

The answer in the linked question is perfect for citations but doesn't help the bibliography. The identical problem occurs both in our real-life .bst as in the MWE. Specifically, the MWE produces for the second item:

> Andersen, T. G., T. Bollerslev, F. X. Diebold, and H. Ebens. 2001.
> “The distribution of realized stock return volatility.” Journal of
> Financial Economics 61(1):43–76.

Our style would be to truncate in the bibliography as follows:

> Andersen, T. G., et al. 2001. “The distribution of realized stock
> return volatility.” Journal of Financial Economics 61(1):43–76.

(Italics lost in copy to plain text: please ignore; ditto for the changed line breaks. The problem is in how authors are listed. Hope this is clear.) Not finding an answer elsewhere, hope I haven't missed anything too obvious.

Here's the MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{abd:2007,
  author      = "Torben G. Andersen and Tim Bollerslev and Francis X. Diebold",
  title       = "Roughing it up: {Including} jump components in the
                measurement, modeling and forecasting of return volatility",
  journal     = "Review of Economics and Statistics",
  year        = 2007,
  volume      = 89,
  number      = 4,
  month       = "November",
  pages       = "701--720",
}

@article{abde:2001,
  author      = "Torben G. Andersen and Tim Bollerslev and Francis X. Diebold
                and Heiko Ebens",
  title       = "The distribution of realized stock return volatility",
  journal     = "Journal of Financial Economics",
  year        = 2001,
  volume      = 61,
  number      = 1,
  month       = "July",
  pages       = "43--76",
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[round,authoryear,comma]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{jf}  % or: jf3
\begin{document}
\citet{abd:2007}; \citet{abde:2001}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```